# Play MP3 on touch event with HTML-CSS-JS

Tags: javascript, mp3, touch-event

could someone help me in finding a way to play an mp3 audio file by touching an image on a touch screen with HTML-CSS-JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>audio with image</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>

<img src="http://www.partyplan123.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/click-here.jpg" onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" ></audio>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why withe the code that I was using, if I centered the image the program would play the audio even when I clicked on the sides of the image. Thank you! On the other side, this only works on chrome and not on explorer

Comment: Have you opened the developer console in IE to check for any JavaScript errors? You can open it by hitting F12 on your keyboard then switching to the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

To play an audio file in HTML, use the `<audio></audio>` tag.
This tag also comes with `<audio controls>` attribute, to add controls like play pause and all.
For a full DOM documentation on this tag go to the [W3 audio tag docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

As for the JS side, use the `onclick()` event for triggering the audio file on touch.

Answer (score 0):

Create an audio element in your html and hide it using `visibility: hidden`.

When the user clicks on the image, handle the click event with Javascript and trigger play on the audio element manually from the handler.

You can refer [here for more documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) on `audio` html api's.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way. This is not inline Javascript so complies to Content Security Policies (CSP's) so if you port to android .apk or to a chromium app, you won't have issues. This is not my code obviously, its from Steven Park on teamtreehouse:
The first way using Jquery:

```
const rollSound = new Audio("./assets/audio/ONEDICE.WAV");
    $('#dice-button').click(e => rollSound.play());
```

Create a a div with the #div-button name, and also another example a version that is not JQuery:

```
const rollSound = new Audio("./assets/audio/ONEDICE.WAV");
    document.getElementById('dice-button').addEventListener("click", e => 
    rollSound.play());
```

You can find it here:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-add-a-sound-when-a-button-is-clicked-jquery

However I have cut and paste it because it took me hours to find that solution after searching for something that fills my needs.